# undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a simple rails app, where useres can leave comments on posts.

When I make a new post, I run into a `undefined method 'user_name' for nil:NilClass` error.

Specifically, the following:

[image: error page]

As you can see in the picture, @post.comments seems to contain a single comment with nil variables.

my comment controller is as follows:

```
before_action :set_post

def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "You commented the hell out of that post!"
        redirect_to @post
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Check the comment form, something went horribly wrong."
        redicect_to @post
    end
end

#...

    private
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end

def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

And my post controller:

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

#...

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
        redirect_to @post
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created! Please check the form."
        render :new
    end
end

#...

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:image, :description)
end

def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Thanks for the help. Sorry for and grammatical errors, I've been up for a while working on this, and am not a great speller when I'm awake.

Comment: Are you sure all your existing records have user_id? Try this in the console `Comment.where(user_id: nil).count` Remove those records if it's not 0.

Comment: None of my existing records have ids Comment.all returns to objects.

Answer (score 1):

try change

```
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

to

```
@comment.user = current_user
```

You need to either make sure `comment` does not get saved without an user/user_id, or you have to handle the case in view where user/user_id is nil

Comment: How can I ensure comments are being saved with the needed data? `comment_params` currently looks like this: `params.require(:comment, :user_id).permit(:content)`, and I'm still getting the error. Why does @post.comments have any elements at all?

Comment: it should be: `params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the name of the user but you are not currently permitting a user_id in your comment_params:

This:

```
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
```

Should be:

```
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
```

It is also possible that your code should be:

```
comment.user.name
```

instead of

```
comment.user.user_name
```

we would need to see your model to confirm. I would not use `user_name` as an attribute of `user`.

Comment: If it were an issue with the method name. why would I be getting a nil:NilClass error? The problem is that I'm creating a comment where all but one of the variables are nil.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments for that post might not have a user. You can use try method here.

```
@comment.try(:user).try(:user_name)
```

But the ideal way to handle this would be to add a presence validation to the user model so that all comments created by any user in future will have a name.

Comment: @ZhongZheng answer is spot on!

Comment: My comment model currently has `validates :user_id, presence: true` (in addition to belongs) is there anything else I should add?